# Getting differents result on wireshark while entering to the same website

Tags: http, networking, wireshark

I'm trying to understand wireshark and how the different protocols works.
If I check the HTTP protocol while entering a website for the first time, on wireshark I see all the HTTP get that happen. If I enter to the same website again I can't see any http on wireshark. What's is happening?

I tried to clear the cache, but I still don't get anything when entering for the second chance.

Answer (score 0):

If you really clear the cache, the browser have to search again on internet. By default on FireFox, you could refresh the page

- left click on reload icon while maintain [Shift] key down.
- with [CTRL]+[F5] or [CTRL]+[Shift]+[R]

Remember to not use capture filter in Wireshark (the file wouldn't keep trace of frames filtered) but use display filter like 'http' in the filter line up in the interface.